# How to increase l2p page size

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I just got done moving my project from my old development machine to my new development machine, both of which are running Visual Studio with VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN.

After a while of banging my head on my desk, I finally got everything copied over and relocated to run from the new location. However, my most recent commit was a pretty large one, and now if I try to compare some of the working copy files with the previous revision, I get the following error:

[image: TortoiseSVN Error Dialog]

I have found the setting to adjust this in the `<repo>\db\fsfs.conf` file here:

```
### This is an expert setting.  Must be a power of 2.
### l2p-page-size is 8192 entries by default.
l2p-page-size = 16384
```

As you can see, I have changed it to 16384 and uncommented that line to see if that would do the trick. However, I am still getting the same error dialog stating that the l2p limit is 8192. Is there something I need to do to tell TortoiseSVN to reload the `fsfs.conf` configuration, or something else I am missing?

I have checked and older revisions are able to display fine, so I don't think that necessarily has anything to do with the migration from the old machine to the new machine aside from maybe different configuration. The same revision is able to be compared on the old development machine with no problems.

**NOTE:**

The old development machine was running TortoiseSVN 1.8.11, which apparently did not have this setting *(the new machine is using TortoiseSVN 1.9.2, the most recent version at the time of this posting)*. Rebooting the new development machine after changing the `fsfs.conf` did the trick, but I'm not sure if there is something simpler I could have done instead.

Comment: How did you migrate your repository? Do you really use VisualSVN Server or VisualSVN for Visual Studio?

Comment: I migrated the repository by using `svnadmin dump` as described here: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/665.cfm, and then I used TortoiseSVN to `relocate` the project to the new location. I do use VisualSVN for Visual Studio to make commits/etc, and VisualSVN Server to host the repository.

Comment: Do you have any errors when running `svnadmin verify` with new repository?

Comment: No errors at all, @IvanZhakov, but thanks for the advice. I changed the settings back to the defaults and everything is working properly after a reboot, even with the default settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `l2p-page-size` option in fsfs.conf should not be changed: it's a page size, not a limit of items. Subversion doesn't have any limits in default configuration. It seems you're experiencing some kind of repository corruption or data was migrated incorrectly. You should verify your repository first using the following command:

```
svnadmin verify <PATH_TO_REPOS>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will give that a try. I will also try changing the l2p limit back to the default value and reboot, and see if that revision still loads correctly.

Comment: Alright, well that is interesting. I went ahead and ran `svnadmin verify` on my repository, and everything verified correctly. I changed the `l2p-page-size` back to 8192 and rebooted, and I am able to view the revision that I was previously having problems with. Seems like a reboot was all that was needed to get everything working properly, totally unrelated to the `fsfs.conf` settings. Strange.